# Quiero hacer más chico el siguiente codigo, ¿Me echan una mano?

Tags: python, pyqt5

1. Modifica texto de un QlineEdit (le_E) desde otro (le_N)

```
self.le_E.editingFinished.connect(self.RellenAut_N)
self.le_N.editingFinished.connect(self.RellenAut_E)
```

2. Rellena automáticamente un QlineEdit al salir

```
    def RellenAut_E(self): #CODE A
        l_N = self.le_N.text()
        l_E = self.le_E.text()

        if not l_N: #Si no hay Cls
            if l_E != None: #Si hay dato en No Cls.:
                self.le_E.clear()
        else: #Si hay Cls
            if not l_E: #Si Cls.: está Vacio...
                l_E = float(l_N) * 25
                l_E = "{:.2f}".format(l_E)
                self.le_E.setText(l_E)
            else: #Si Cls.: contiene Dato 
                 if l_N != None:
                    self.le_E.clear()
                    l_E = float(l_N) * 25
                    l_E = "{:.2f}".format(l_E)
                    self.le_E.setText(l_E)
```

3. Otro código para cambiar el siguiente QlineEdit

```
    def RellenAut_N(self): #CODE B
        l_E = self.le_E.text()
        l_N = self.le_N.text()

        if not l_E: #Si no hay efect
            if l_N != None: #Si hay dato en No.:
                self.le_N.clear() #Limpiar No.:
        else: #Si hay Efect
            if not l_N: #Si No.: está Vacio...
                l_N = float(l_E) / 25
                l_N = "{:.2f}".format(l_N)
                l_N = l_N.replace('.00','')
                # l_N = round(l_N)#Redondea sin decimal
                self.le_N.setText(l_N)
            else: #Si No.: contiene Dato 
                 if l_E != None:
                    self.le_N.clear()
                    l_N = float(l_E) / 25
                    l_N = "{:.2f}".format(l_N)
                    l_N = l_N.replace('.00','')
                    # l_N = round(l_N)#Redondea sin decimal
                    self.le_N.setText(l_N)
```

Comment: Si te resulta difícil leer el código es porque no es código limpio. Usa nombres más descriptivos e introduce alguna que otra función.

Comment: Seguro que `l_E` llega a ser `None` en algún momento? Si no es el caso puedes deshacerte de una parte del código.

Comment: @Mateo, Gracias por lo comentado, el código realiza su función perfectamente, solo quiero hacerlo más chico sin que altere los resultados, sigo trabajándolo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Los dos últimos IF son idénticos, excepto por `self.le_N.clear()`.

Refactorizando para eliminar líneas duplicadas.

```
def RellenAut_N(self): 

     if not l_E: #Si no hay efect
         if l_N != None: #Si hay dato en No.:
             self.le_N.clear() #Limpiar No.:

     else: #Si hay Efect
         if 1_N and l_E != None:
             self.le_N.clear()
             
         if not l_N or l_E != None: 
             l_N = float(l_E) / 25
             l_N = "{:.2f}".format(l_N)
             l_N = l_N.replace('.00','')
             self.le_N.setText(l_N)
```

Comment: Se agradece mucho, Candid Moe, me ahorras 9 lineas de codigo, solo que al seguir editando el QlineEdit, borra el valor añadido.. pongo capturas...

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente !! el resultado del refactorizado sin afectar comportamiento.

```
def rellenadoA(self):
    l_N = self.le_N.text()
    l_E = self.le_E.text()
    if not l_N:
        if l_E != None: self.le_E.clear()
    else:
        if not l_E: self.rellE(l_E, l_N)
        else:  
            self.le_E.clear()
            self.rellE(l_E, l_N)

def rellE(self, l_E, l_N):
    l_E = float(l_N) * 25
    l_E = "{:.2f}".format(l_E)
    self.le_E.setText(l_E)
    self.le_P.setFocus()
```